# How to use Oracle SQLdeveloper with HSQL / Hypersonic DB's JDBC driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, hsqldb, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'd like to use Oracle's SQLdeveloper to visualize my HSQLDB tables. 
An instruction on how to use it with MySQL can be found on https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=564 ... and I know that Oracle points to a location where to download all JDBC drivers.

With MySQL this worked, however, including the JAR file from HSQLDB (here: hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar) did not make a new tab show up (as is the case with MySQL).

Is there a way to "convince" SQLdeveloper working with HSQLDB and JDBC?
FYI, I am using Squirrel too but it's not as comfortable to work with compared to SQLdeveloper.

Comment: Old thread, but for anyone coming to this late and wanting to view the link above, it does work but has an extra dot com in it. Here's the still-working link: http://blogs.techrepublic.com/programming-and-development/?p=564

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same thing, then found this:

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4241526&#4241526

So basically Oracle doesn't support it, and you can't add a new TAB on your own, even if you have the JDBC driver.

You can try other tool like ExecuteQuery (executequery dot org)